# Is $f: F \to R, \ (a_j)_{j \in \mathbb N} \mapsto \sum_{j \in \mathbb N} \ a_j $ bijective and find the inverse function!

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, transformation

$F$ is the set of the sequences in $\mathbb C$ and $R$ is the set of the series in $\mathbb C$.

$f: F \to R, \ (a_j)_{j \in \mathbb N} \mapsto \sum_{j \in \mathbb N} \ a_j $

Now $\sum_{j \in \mathbb N} \ a_j $ should be the sequence of the partial sums $(s_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ with $s_n =\sum_{j \in \mathbb N} \ a_j $

1. **Show this transformation is BIJECTIVE!**
2. **Find the inverse function!**

---

Thoughts:

- Because $F$ is the set of the sequences and set of the series $R$ is the sequence of the partial sums => **$F=R$**
- So $f: F \to F, f(a)=y$ with $y_n:=\sum_{j=1}^n  \ a_j$ for $a= (a_j)_{j \in \mathbb N}$
- inverse function: $f^{-1}: F \to F,f^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^n  \ a_j\mapsto R(a_i)$ with $a_i\sum_{j=1}^i a_i -\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} a_i$

---

Questions:

1. **How can I proove that it is bijective? (I think the sets F,R have the same cardinality)**
2. **Is the inverse function correct?**

Comment: convergent series? formal power series? ;

Comment: The inverese functin is correct, but better be written $s_n-s_{n-1}$ I guess (with the implicit assumption $s_0=0$).

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Can I conclude that it is bijective BECAUSE there is an INVERSE FUNCTION?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Hagen von Eitzen commented, your inverse function is correct, and you can conclude that it is bijective because there is an inverse. Yet I would like to point out a pair of similar operators which might be quite known to you.

Let $D : C^\infty \to C^\infty$ be an operator on the set of infinitely-differentiable functions given by:
$$D(f) = f' = x\mapsto \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
and set $I : C^\infty \to C^\infty$ be defined as
$$I(f) = x\mapsto\int_{[0,x)} f(t)\ \mathrm{d}t$$

Then, $D\big(I(f)\big) = f$ and $I\big(D(f)\big) = x\mapsto f(x) - f(0)$ (thanks to @Berci for correction; also, for convenience, we could consider only functions with $f(0) = 0$). Does these two seem familiar?

Now, if we were to adapt these operators to functions $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$, we could write:

\begin{align}
\Delta(f) &= n\mapsto\frac{f(n+1)-f(n)}{1}\\
S(f) &= n \mapsto \sum_{k \in [0,n)\cap\mathbb{N}} f(k) = n \mapsto \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} f(k)
\end{align}
assuming convention where $\sum_{k=0}^{-1} f(k) = 0$. Simple calculation shows that $\Delta\big(S(f)\big) = f = S\big(\Delta(f)\big)$. For more, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference).

Now there is a very short step from $\Delta$ and $S$ to the two functions of yours.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: We don't have $I(D(f))=f$, but $I(D(f))=f-f(0)$.

Comment: @Berci You are right, fixed now, thanks!